# Overriding and Implementing toString

Tags: java, overriding, implementation, tostring

I'm writing code for an application that keeps track of a student’s food purchases at a campus cafeteria. There's two classes - **Student**, which holds overloaded constructors & appropriate getter & setter methods; and **MealCard**, which holds a class variable to track the number of meal cards issued, appropriate getter & setter methods, a purchaseItem() method, a purchasePoints() method & an overriddden toString() method. There's a **Tester class** also.

How do I override the toString method in *MealCard* from *Student*? It won't accept name, age or address - and I know they're private.

And in the tester class, how do I implement toString() to show the user information?

My code so far is:

```
public class Student {

// Instance Variables
private String name;
private int age;
private String address;

// Default Constructor
public Student() {
    this("Not Given", 0, "Not Given");
}

// Parameterized constructor that takes in values
public Student(String name, int age, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}

// Getters and Setters
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

// toString() to be overriden
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + this.name + "\n" + "Age: " + this.age + "\n" + "Address: " + this.address;
}
}
```

`

```
public class MealCard {

private static int numberOfMealCards;
private final static int DEFAULT_BALANCE = 1000;
private int itemValue;
private int topUpValue;
public int newBalance;

// Getters and Setters
public int getItemValue() {
    return itemValue;
}
public void setItemValue(int itemValue) {
    this.itemValue = itemValue;
}

public int getTopUpValue() {
    return topUpValue;
}
public void setTopUpValue(int topUpValue) {
    this.topUpValue = topUpValue;
}

// purchaseItem method for when students buy food
public int purchaseItem() {
    newBalance = DEFAULT_BALANCE - itemValue;
    return newBalance;
}

// purchasePoints method for students topping up their meal card balance
public int purchasePoints() {
    newBalance = DEFAULT_BALANCE + topUpValue;
    return newBalance;
}

// Overriden toString method
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + getName + "\n" + "Age: " + getAge + "\n" + "Address: " + getAddress +
            "\n" + "Meal Card Balance: " + newBalance + "\n" + "Number of Meal Cards: " + numberOfMealCards;
}

}
```

Comment: The superclass already has a toString, so you don't need to reinvent it in the subclass. The `toString` in your subclass should provide a string representation of the subclass's unique data, and if you need anything from the superclass, call it's method directly with `super.toString()`. You override it in the same way you did in your `Student` class, using the same `@Override` annotation.

Comment: You also need a pair of parentheses on all your method calls in the MealCard `toString()` method if you don't use `super.toString()`

Comment: @RyanJ there's no inheritance, does this still apply?

Comment: @LauraBerry sorry, I rushed to judgment. If there's no inheritance, then you're not overriding (technically, you always override `Object`s implementation). However, overriding `Object`'s `toString` should be done in the same manner as with student, but for your `MealCard` class. It should provide a string representation of that class. A class that contains a reference to a `MealCard` will use the `toString` method on that object to obtain that information.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it might be easier to show this in an answer, rather than in extensive commenting.

Providing an implementation of `toString` in a class boils down to providing a `String` representation of that class, nothing more. What you're trying to do is provide string information for an unrelated class (`Student`), of which `MealCard` knows nothing (and shouldn't) about.

How you accomplish what you want is probably to have `Student` update to hold a reference to a `MealCard` (read: each student *has a* `MealCard`), and in your `Student` implementation of `toString`, use your meal card reference to get `toString` data from the meal card class.

Ex:

```
public class MealCard {

    //... skipped over for simplicity

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item Value = " + this.getItemValue() + ", TopUpValue = " + this.getTopUpValue() + " ... "; // and so on...
    } 
}
```

Then in `Student`, have a reference to `MealCard` and use that in `toString`

```
public class Student {

    // other student data
    MealCard mealCard;  // set in constructor

    // ... other methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " ... other student data... MealCard = " + getMealCard().toString(); // use the mealcard reference to get string info

    }
}
```

Make sense?